# NodeJS require doesn't cache one single file

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, caching, require

After finishing my IT project near-completely, I tried adding some unit testing as it is in the specifications (yes, I know that this is technically the wrong order). For this, I use `mocha`, combined with `chai`, `chai-http` and `sinon`. It all went well until I tried stubbing out my database file `bin\database.js` while testing the routes. This is a minimal working example of the database file:

```js
/* jshint esversion: 6, node: true */
'use strict';
console.log('loaded'); // For verifying that the cache doesn't work

function def(some, callback) {
    callback();
}

function defArray(some, callback) {
    callback(undefined, []);
}

function defNumber(some, callback) {
    callback(undefined, 0);
}

module.exports = {
    Category: function() {},
    addCategory: def,
    modifyCategory: def,
    removeCategory: def,
    getCategories: defArray,
    getCategory: def,
    countCategories: defNumber,

    Question: function() {},
    addQuestion: def,
    modifyQuestion: def,
    answeredQuestion: def,
    removeQuestion: def,
    getQuestions: defArray,
    getQuestion: def,
    countQuestions: defNumber,

    Highscore: function() {},
    addHighscore: def,
    removeHighscore: def, 
    getHighscores: defArray,
    highscoreSort(a, b) {
        return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
    },
    countHighscores: defNumber
};
```

The code using sinon looks like this:

```js
before(function() {
    sinon.stub(database, 'getCategories', function(filter, callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('getCategories');
            callback(null, []);
        }, 30);
    });
     sinon.stub(database, 'getQuestions', function(filter, callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('getQuestions');
            callback(null, []);
        }, 30);
    });
});

afterEach(function() {
    database.getCategories.reset();
    database.getQuestions.reset();
});

after(function() {
    database.getCategories.restore();
    database.getQuestions.restore();
});
```

If I now run the mocha tests with `set NODE_ENV=testing & mocha --watch` (the test-file being test\test-routes.js, don't mind the env-variable, it's for less clutter in the console), it works fine in the first run, printing the "getQuestions" and "getCategories" where it get's called:

```js
routes
  admin route
    GET requests
      √ should redirect from /admin to /admin/home (542ms)
      √ answers correctly on GET to/admin/home (231ms)
getCategories
      √ answers correctly on GET to/admin/category (696ms)
getCategories
getQuestions
      √ answers correctly on GET to/admin/question (584ms)
      √ answers correctly on GET to/admin/highscore (299ms)
```

However, when the `--watch` catches in after I changed something in the test file, these are missing from the output. In addition, this seems to be the only file that isn't cached at all, verified like this:

```js
console.log(Object.keys(require.cache).length);
var database = require('../bin/database');
console.log(Object.keys(require.cache).length);
var server   = require('../bin/www');
var chai     = require('chai');
var chaiHTTP = require('chai-http');
var expect   = chai.expect;
var sinon    = require('sinon');
console.log(Object.keys(require.cache).length);
```

The first time, this prints `72`, `73` and `354`. On further invocations, it prints `539`, `540` and `540`, suggesting that `bin\database.js` did *not* get cached.

Can anyone provide further insights as to what might cause this behaviour? I do not clear the cache manually in any other file, being the only file to do so.

I am running node v6.8.1 with mocha 3.1.2, sinon 1.17.6, and chai 3.5.0.